# How to use integral - $x^2$

Tags: integration

I want to count integral of $f(x)=x^2$ in range for example $0$ through $10$.

What should I read to do it by myself and apply it to other funcs ?

Answer (score 3):

First learn differential calculus, then integral calculus. The formula to be used here is :$$\int_{a}^{b} x^{n} \ dx = \bigg[\displaystyle \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg]^{b}_{a}$$

Note: the answer will be $\frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: I don't know how to put the limits near the bracket. Anyone can tell me how to put it.

Comment: Maybe $\bigg[\displaystyle \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg]^{b}_{a}$ = \bigg[\displaystyle \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg]^{b}_{a} or using \bigg| on the right side instead of the brackets.

Comment: You're welcome (wow, you are quick, I was still polishing my comment)

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for $x^{-1}$